# How to use up-to-date with time indications

Tags: word-usage

The last time my data were updated in my report was last midnight.
I want to write below the report something like:
"The data in this report are up-to-date to last midnight" but it sounds awful.
How should I write?

Yes, I know I could simply write "Last Update: 18/03/2019 00:00" but I would like to write it in a different way.
Thankx.
W.

Comment: Is the run-date  of the report shown anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data in this report is up-to-date as of midnight last night.